# Formatting pre-formatted text

Tags: html, email

I have a Unix Shell script which produces a plain text report.  Horizontal alignment is achieved by inserting spaces so that the output appears to be in columns in the terminal.

```
Caption        Caption          Caption
--------       --------         --------
Line 1         value 1          value 2
Line 2         value b          bla bla
Line 3         value 1          value 2
Line 4         value b          bla bla
```

The report is automated to run regularly and a copy is sent via email.  To make the formatting look right in a mail client I set the content-type to HTML and added `<PRE>` pre-formatting tags around the entire message content.

This works well enough.  However I would like to highlight certain lines, eg by changing the font to set the text and background color.  How could I best do that?

I can replace the `<PRE>`...`</PRE>` with a span to set a Mono-width font but how do I retain the blank spaces to keep the column/table appearance?

I tried to use actual HTML tables but this only works in some mail clients, in others the same message is illegible because most of the text becomes strung out in a very narrow (1 to 3 characters wide) very tall column.  Also setting formatting options on table attributes behave wildly different between the few email clients that I have available for my own testing!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032652/how-do-i-get-an-html-text-area-with-monospaced-text-using-css

Comment: Can't you wrap the lines you want to highlight in `<span>`s and set the appropriate inline style? Or perhaps `<b>` (or `<strong>`) in case the inline style is not honoured.

Comment: Tags like <span>, <b>, and <strong> cannot be used inside <PRE>...</PRE> tags.  I don't know what will happen if I use something like `<b><pre>Text Line Here</pre></b>`

Comment: You have it back to front... yes you can use `<span>`, `<b>` and `<strong>` elements inside a `<pre>` element. You can use any _inline_ element inside a `<pre>`, but you cannot use block-level elements, so your example `<b><pre>Text Line Here</pre></b>` would be invalid.

Comment: @w3d That's why YOU are the guy with the 9k rep.

Comment: @Johan, now he's up to 35k rep. I thought it was a tech myth when I first heard about it. Evidently not :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish per-line control of the rendered text you should consider some kind of automation on your Shell script in order to include the proper code in the output. A good option is to create an html file which can then be sent like an email template or which pre-formatted text you can simply copy/paste from your browser to your email client's message compositing window.

Something like this can work:

## CSS:

```
.title {
    color: #00f;
}

.yellow {
    color: #f00;
    background: #ff0;
}

.green {
    color: #00f;
    background: #0f0;
}

.red {
    color: #ff0;
    background: #f00;
}
```

## HTML:

```
<pre>Hello world!</pre>
<pre class="title">Caption        Caption          Caption</pre>
<pre>--------       --------         --------</pre>
<pre class="regular">Line 1         value 1          value 2</pre>
<pre class="yellow">Line 2         value b          bla bla</pre>
<pre class="green">Line 3         value 1          value 2</pre>
<pre class="red">Line 4         value b          bla bla</pre>
```

### The result:

[image: formatted text]

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/geppettvs/etycazov/

You can define as many styles as you wish and instructing your Shell script will do the work for you if you drop the results in a file.html in order to create the web contents you wish to share.

Good luck!

Comment: I like your suggestion, I'll try it tomorrow.  My HTML / CSS skills are very basic, so it didn't occur to me to add styles to the PRE tag itself.  I won't change the report generation script to add any tags to its output, but the task that runs to send the email can process the report to format the message as HTML.

Comment: You may need to use `background-color` rather than `background` for better email client support. Ref: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: Your answer and the comments by @w3d led me to the solution.  I'm still using a single set of PRE....PRE tags, but including background-color inside of these on individual lines.  For some reason I thought/assumed all HTML markup inside PRE tags will be rendered in the browser.  Note though that the CSS must be inline for better Email client support.

Comment: Good to know you found a workaround and this has been useful for you. Yes, you can embed the CSS inline or, you can point your CSS to an online server, which can do the work for you. In first instance we should consider that people will need an Internet connection in order to read the emails, so the email client can gather the CSS from wherever you place it. Nevertheless, inline CSS can also be useful for offline work. :)

Comment: "point your CSS to an online server" - several webmail/email clients do not support linking to an external stylesheet. And any security software the user has installed could actively block it.

Comment: Absolutely agree @w3d, nevertheless, people may choose if they wish their email client to accept such behaviour, and instruct their security software to override such blocking. I am guessing this information is just for certain people who needs the information on the list, so it's a good idea to consider linking some data on external servers so that the assets won't be loaded with the email which will result in lower data consumption for mobile devices if (and just if) people won't allow their email clients to download all the assets and yet see the data.

Comment: Additionally, by using external assets we can have better results for those email clients which allow the usage of external images and css files, and limited -yet useful- data for those who won't wish them. I mean, a "heavy" style supercharged version for people who will accept it and a "light" version for the people you are referring to. The fact is that we can't limit the scenarios just because of it seems kinda impossible because of security facts or software/user limitations. By using CSS the limits are just your imagination. Let it out!

Comment: And... remember they can always use a different email client. :)